# Where can i find akka.cloud package?

Tags: scala, cloud, cluster-computing, akka

Can someone point me to the Akka version that has the package akka.cloud.cluster? I am currently using Akka 1.2-RC6. google searches on this topic result in broken links about Cloudy Akka...

Answer (score 2):

Cloudy Akka was described [here](http://letitcrash.posterous.com/clustered-actors-with-cloudy-akka) as a suite of commercial add-on modules for Akka.

The original company developing Akka have since merged with [Typesafe](http://www.typesafe.com).

The latest seems to be [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/6OSYx3ZU5Mo) topic from the akka user mailing list, specifically:

> "the Cloudy Akka project is split up:
>
> - the stuff interesting for developers (like distribution etc) is
>     going to be free and part of Akka 2.0
> - the stuff interesting for operations is going to remain commercial.
>
> This 'operational functionality' is renamed to Atmos."

Answer (score 1):

Clustering functionality will be part of the 2.0 Release. At the moment the best way to use it, is to check it out from: https://github.com/jboner/akka

Please be aware that 2.0 is work in progress. Lots of things can change until the release.