# Akka Cluster Java API sample

Tags: java, scala, cluster-computing, akka, akka-cluster

I am pretty interested in testing out the 2.0-SNAPSHOT Akka cluster features, but for my purposes would like to do this in Java.

I have read through the example here:  http://letitcrash.posterous.com/clustered-actors-with-cloudy-akka

But the API seems to have changed enough (Cluster.startLocalCluster() doesn't exist anymore?), and the documentation is sparse enough (to be expected), that my tinkering is going very slow.

Is anybody aware of a small small sample application that stands up a couple of local nodes via Akka clustering in Java?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I would not recommend playing around with cluster functionality, too much can change until release. See also [where-can-i-find-akka-cloud-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422380/where-can-i-find-akka-cloud-package/7428284#7428284).

Comment: Thanks Christian - actually, monitoring the changes as the library gets closer to release is a plus to me rather than a concern.